# Cannot access base class's members in the derived class's XAML in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a `DialogView` class that is derived from a base class `Dialog` which is again derived from `ContentView`, ie. `DialogView : Dialog : ContentView`. I am getting errors that are mentioned later.

**Here is my XAML code (DialogView.xaml)**

```xml
<controls:DialogView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     ...
                     xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views.Controls"
                     IsVisible="False"> <!--error: The property 'IsVisible' was not found in 'DialogView'-->

    <ContentView.Content>  <!--error: The attachable property 'Content' was not found in 'ContentView'
        ...
    </ContentView.Content>
</controls:DialogView>
```

**Here is my C# Code (DialogView.xaml.cs)**

```cs
public class Dialog : ContentView
{
    // Some properties
}

[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class DialogView : Dialog  // error: Partial declarations of View must not specify different base classes
{
}
```

**Errors:**

- `DialogView` class is a partial class that has view defined in XAML. I want to access `IsVisible` property of it in the XAML, but I cannot access it, I am getting error: **The property 'IsVisible' was not found in DialogView**. `IsVisible` is a property of `VisualElement` which is available in `ContentView` as it is derived from `VisualElement` at multiple levels then why is it not available in `DialogView` as `DialogView` is derived from `ContentView`.
- I also cannot use `<ContentView.Content>` inside `DialogView`'s XAML. I am getting an error: **The attachable property 'Content' was not found in 'ContentView'**.
- I am also getting error **Partial declarations of View must not specify different base classes** where I am defining `public partial class DialogView : Dialog`.

In C#, public members of base classes are directly accessible in the derived class as derived class and base class share an **is-a** relationship. Is that not a case in XAML? How can I access base class's members in derived class while in XAML.

Comment: Inheritance works in XAML the way that you expect. So something is wrong somewhere. Is this an Intellisense error, or a Build error? In a situation such as this, Intellisense won't work correctly until *after* a *successful* Build. So if it is just Intellisense that is complaining , the fix is to Build Solution. Is it possible that you have some other problem elsewhere, that prevents you from making a *successful* build? You might need to comment out some code (or even temporarily Exclude From Project that xaml file), until you have successfully built the project with Dialog and DialogView.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, I am also getting an error in C# Code behind **Partial declarations of View must not specify different base classes** where I am defining `DialogView : Dialog` class.

Comment: Yep. That symptom means you misunderstand what you need to do, to accomplish your goal. You've latched on to some wrong understanding of how to customize a view. Let go of what you think you know, and start over with the simple case: VS / Add New Item / ContentView. Once that works, examine what goes where in the xaml and the cs. THEN take a look at my answer's "Alternative Solution". That might be all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that the xaml is in `DialogView.xaml`. If that's correct, then you've made a mistake.

The root element's type must be the **parent class**. Use `x:Class` to declare the class itself:

```
<controls:Dialog xmlns...
    x:Class="YourNamespace.DialogView">
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION**

Its possible that you are overcomplicating the situation.

Why do you define **both** `Dialog` and `DialogView` classes, in `DialogView.xaml.cs`? That is possible, but almost certainly does not do what you want.

Instead do this:

1. Add a new `ContentView` to your project, named `Dialog`. This will add two files, `Dialog.xaml` and `Dialog.xaml.cs`. In those files, put everything you want to exist in **all** your subclasses of `Dialog`.
2. Add another new `ContentView` to your project, named `DialogView`. This will add two more files, `DialogView.xaml` and `DialogView.xaml.cs`. In the xaml, change `<ContentView ...` to `<controls:Dialog ...`. In the cs, change `public partial DialogView : ContentView` to `public partial DialogView : Dialog`. Thus, your DialogView is now a Dialog. Build Solution (so intellisense will correctly see the parent change from ContentView to Dialog.) Now add to xaml and cs as desired.

NOTE: At some time in the future (or maybe its already possible in 2022 Preview), I expect it will become possible for VS to directly create a xaml-based control that inherits from your custom view class. Then you won't have to do a kludge like I do above for DialogView, where I first create a ContentView, and then rename the parent class.

Comment: You are right, but why can't I have root element of `DialogView` type as it is derived from `Dialog` which is derived from `ContentView`. I also cannot have root element of `ContentView` type, I am getting error: **Partial declarations of View must not specify different base classes**. Isn't `DialogView` and `Dialog` are of `ContentView` type.

Comment: You can have root element of DialogVIew. BUT that would NOT be stored in a file named DialogView.xaml. DialogView.xaml is the xaml for ALL DialogView's - it goes with DialogView.xaml.cs. Look at any example of declaring a custom view, and you should be able to see what I mean. You are confusing two different concepts: the declaration of a new view subclass, versus the use of that subclass to make multiple views, each of which can be customized. Either delete `DialogView.xaml`, or put in it xaml that you want in **all** places that DialogView appears...

Comment: ... If a file named `DialogView.xaml` exists, then it must have a root element that matches the cs declaration. cs says `DialogView : Dialog`, so xaml must say `<controls:Dialog ...x:Class="YourNamespace.DialogView">`. Get that to work, then you can define a new class `DialogView1` (or whatever). That will have `DialogView1.xaml` with `<controls:DialogView ... x:Class="YourNamespace.DialogView`">, and `DialogView1.xaml.cs` with `public partial class DialogView1 : DialogView ...`.

Comment: NOTE: If you don't need *multiple* DialogView's, each with their own custom xaml or cs, then its as simple as what I show in my answer. **I recommend getting that to work first.** Thus you will have succeeded in making **one** DialogView. Once that works, you can do what I describe in previous comment, to make different DialogViews.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, I needed universal `Dialog` class that will be derived for various types of dialogs like LoadingPanel, DialogBoxes, etc. I got it working at *The root element's type must be the **parent** class.*. But I did not get it. Why does root element needs to be of **parent class** type? Why I cannot specify anything that is derived from `ContentView` or the `ContentView` itself. Why does it need to specify just the immediate parent class of the specified class in `x:Class="namespace.DialogView`?

Comment: ... all the 3 classes are of `ContentView` type then why does it need to specify only the immediate parent class type at the root element?

Comment: The **root element** is special. Its equivalent to `public partial YourClass : ParentClass`. xaml needs *some* way to say "what is the parent class" and "what is the class you are defining". Otherwise, how would it know what you are inheriting from? It does that with a root element `<ParentClass ... x:Class="YourNameSpace.YourClass>`. Could Microsoft have instead added an attribute `x:Parent="ParentNameSpace.ParentClass"`? Perhaps. But they chose this way.